# Inconsistent behaviour of GregorianCalendar when created from ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-time, week-number, gregorian-calendar, java.util.calendar

I'm writing some integration of legacy code that expects date/time as a GregorianCalendar.

So, I'm creating the GregorianCalendar using `from(ZonedDateTime)` method.

However, the result is showing some inconsistent behaviour when the GregorianCalendar is created from the ZonedDateTime versus when the GregorianCalendar is created, let's say, from a string parsing or even from epoch millis. For example, when setting the Calendar day_of_week. To demonstrate this (https://onecompiler.com/java/3yssz4q86):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final GregorianCalendar calendarPure = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
    printInfo(calendarPure);

    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    final ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
    
    final GregorianCalendar calendarFromZdt = GregorianCalendar.from(zdtNow);
    printInfo(calendarFromZdt);
    
    final GregorianCalendar calendarFromZdtEpoch = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendarFromZdtEpoch.setTimeInMillis(zdtNow.toInstant().toEpochMilli());

    printInfo(calendarFromZdtEpoch);
  }
  
  private static void printInfo(GregorianCalendar cal) {
    System.out.printf("Now: %tc%n", cal);
    System.out.printf("Last Sunday: %tc%n", getLastSunday(cal));
    System.out.printf("Week of Year: %d%n", cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
    System.out.printf("Time in Millis: %d%n", cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.printf("toString(): %s%n", cal);
    System.out.println();
  }
  
  public static GregorianCalendar getLastSunday(GregorianCalendar referenceDate) {
    final GregorianCalendar lastSundayMidNight = (GregorianCalendar)referenceDate.clone();
    lastSundayMidNight.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    return lastSundayMidNight;
  }

}
```

The output is:

```
Now: Wed Dec 28 16:45:36 PST 2022
Last Sunday: Sun Dec 25 16:45:36 PST 2022
Week of Year: 53
Time in Millis: 1672274736631
toString(): java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1672274736631,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2022,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=53,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=28,DAY_OF_YEAR=362,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=45,SECOND=36,MILLISECOND=631,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]

Now: Wed Dec 28 16:45:36 PST 2022
Last Sunday: Sun Jan 01 16:45:36 PST 2023
Week of Year: 52
Time in Millis: 1672274736668
toString(): java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1672274736668,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2022,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=52,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=28,DAY_OF_YEAR=362,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=45,SECOND=36,MILLISECOND=668,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]

Now: Thu Dec 29 00:45:36 UTC 2022
Last Sunday: Sun Dec 25 00:45:36 UTC 2022
Week of Year: 53
Time in Millis: 1672274736668
toString(): java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1672274736668,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2022,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=53,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=29,DAY_OF_YEAR=363,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=45,SECOND=36,MILLISECOND=668,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

I noticed that, from `GregorianCalendar.toString()` that prints the internal fields a different in `firstDayOfWeek` and `minimalDaysInFirstWeek`. That could be the cause for the divergence in the after results. I wonder where the GregorianCalendar is getting these values from. Maybe there is a way to set something on ZonedDateTime object that will ensure the results will be the same? Couldn't find anything on javadocs.

Note: Please, don't tell me not to use `GregorianCalendar`. I know, I know. I'm just writing an integration for two pieces of code that I'm not allowed to modify, one uses `GregorianCalendar` (sigh), the other uses `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: What is your LOCALE?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're using `GregorianCalendar` for?  It's based on `Calendar`, which is known to be almost impossible to use correctly.

Comment: I think the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69300459/18157) is what you're looking for.  Java has ***three*** different locale settings, and a careful reading of the Javadoc shows the "pure" `GregorianCalendar` and the one from ZDT use _different_ locales.  As @LouisWasserman says, avoid `GregorianCalendar` if at all possible, it's a minefield.

Comment: Pro Tip: The only absolutely "safe" object that has no pitfalls is `Instant`. It represents a unique point on the time line.  Everything else has nuances related to politics and representation, and is incredibly messy. The newer `java.time` classes are a huge improvement, but there are still traps and unintuitive behaviors.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` uses ISO chronology, so the `GregorianCalendar` that you get from it uses ISO weeks: the week starts on Monday, and week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days of the new year in it. The `GregorianCalendar` that you create yourself follows your default locale (as @JimGarrison hinted), which probably has a different definition of weeks.  Try printing `cal.getFirstDayOfWeek()` and `cal.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`. You may also try using the corresponding setters.

Comment: Or from the docs: *The `getFirstDayOfWeek()` and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` values are initialized using locale-dependent resources when constructing a `GregorianCalendar`. The week determination is compatible with the ISO 8601 standard when `getFirstDayOfWeek()` is `MONDAY` and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` is `4`, which values are used in locales where the standard is preferred. These values can explicitly be set by calling `setFirstDayOfWeek()` and `setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`.*

Comment: And about the `from` method: *the return GregorianCalendar ... uses ISO 8601 standard for week definitions, which has `MONDAY` as the `FirstDayOfWeek` and `4` as the value of the `MinimalDaysInFirstWeek`.*

Comment: (What I said also means that [the documentation of `from()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from(java.time.ZonedDateTime)) is telling a lie when it says *Obtains an instance of `GregorianCalendar` with the default locale from a `ZonedDateTime` object.*. The default locale plays no effective role in the creation of the `GregorianCalendar`.)

Comment: All of the above suggests: _"Friends don't let friends use `GregorianCalendar`"_

Comment: Well... As I said... I'm just making a bridge from an API to another. The target one uses GregorianCalendar and there is nothing I can do about it.

Comment: Adding `calendarFromZdt.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);` and `calendarFromZdt.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(1);` did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V. Your comments put all together completely answers the question. Put all together in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Great to read. I no longer contribute answers to Stack Overflow for reasons that I try to explain in [my proflie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v). Please, if you put together the answer — I can’t promise to accept the answer, but will be happy to upvote it (and you can accept it yourself 12 hours later).